# AngularMaterial Dependancy Giving Errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Im getting errors when i add the 'ngMaterial' dependency for some reason! I will show my files, then error.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:400,500,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dist/css/vendor.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/js/vendor.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css" type="text/css" />


    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>


</head>


    <body ng-app="Hive">

 <!--<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">-->
    <!-- Main View -->

      <div ui-view class="main_view">
      </div>


   <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-energized">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Discussions" icon="ion-android-contacts" ui-sref="discussions">
          <ion-nav-view name="discussions-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Board" icon="ion-ios-list-outline" ui-sref="board">
          <ion-nav-view name="list-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>


             <ion-tab title="Me" icon="ion-android-happy" ui-sref="me">
          <ion-nav-view name="profile-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>


  </body>


</html>
```

app.module.js:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('Hive', [
            //Deps
            'ionic',
            'firebase',
            'ngMaterial'
        ]
    );

});
```

Error:

```
vendor.min.js:3 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/nomod?p0=Hive
vendor.min.js:3 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=Hive&p1=Error%3A%20…users.io%2Famanuel2%2Fhive%2Fassets%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fvendor.min.js%3A3%3A9097)
```

Help Would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the reference of angularjs, Load it like below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.8 used here -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Working [`Ionic app with Material`](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/kXJzaN)

Comment: No it dosent work. I copied all your thing , but still dosent work. And also i already have the CDN's if you see the index.html

Comment: @Dsafds Did you check the application  i have added?

Comment: Yes sir. i sure did

Comment: @Dsafds Its a working sample! why do you say it does not work?

Comment: We are coding it here: https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/hive . can you help? I dont know why!!

Comment: @Dsafds wait let me fix it